# Error with encoding when formatting label

Tags: python, python-2.7, format

I am trying to format the labels (e.g. 1000-1200) to 1,000-1,200€)

This is working correctly:

```
labels = ["{:,}-{:,}".format(int(i[0].split("-")[0]), int(i[0].split("-")[1])) for i in labels]

['600-800', '1,000-1,200', '1,800-2,000', '2,600-2,800', '3,000-3,200']
```

But when I try to set the € symbol:

```
labels = ["u'{:,}-{:,}€'".format(int(i[0].split("-")[0]), int(i[0].split("-")[1])) for i in labels]
```

I am getting:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 9-10: unexpected end of data
```

An idea how to correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `u` flag for the string literal itself, rather than quoting it as part of the string:

```
labels = [u'{:,}-{:,}€'.format(int(i[0].split("-")[0]), int(i[0].split("-")[1])) for i in labels]
```